# Python socket: why the server can only accept 6 requests in select?

Tags: python, sockets, select

Recently I was doing a socket project in python, mainly in the company's network server to deploy a program, as the inner network and external network communication bridge.

The architecture is as follows: Suppose C is our server, there are two hosts A and B:

- B is the "bridge" with A and C, which use port 83 to connect with server C, use port 80 to connect with A.(we can call the connection with A and B is：socket_msg)
- A use port 80 to listen B , and another port 81 is used to listen other clients.

When a client sends a request to A's 8081 port,

1. A will send a message to B through socket_msg to require a new connection.
2. when B receive the "Establish Required", it establish a new connection(new_conn) with A.
3. Then A send the client's data to B through the new_conn, and B send them to C and get the reply, which later will be sent back to A and to the client.

**I used the "select" in both A and B**, for the rotation to listen to requests from clients.

The question now is that I use the web page(eg: 127.0.0.1:8081) to send requests to A, a total of 21 requests, but **A always can accept only six requests**, like that:
[The request condition in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPio2.png)
And when I use  `netstat -na | findstr 8081` in cmd, I receive that:
[netstat result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nij9k.png)

I was wondering the question is that the **client sockets to A cannot be closed  correctly**, but when I add the code `s.close()` after the readable client socket send back all the reply, I check the web page request, it downs to only one reuqest!

I don't know if I describe the question clear, but could you please help me? I'am looking for your guys advice!

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on but looking at the output from Chrome and netstat I suspect that the browser is still waiting for the end of the responses and will send the pending requests only when the currently active requests are finished. Why the browser waits is unknown but my guess is that there is something in your application which results in this, like a incompatible implementation of the HTTP protocol or similar.